# Is it possible to disply the ROADMAP without label using Google Maps JavaScript API V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API V3 to display a map. I love the familiar yellow/brownish ROADMAP I have no use for the labels (street names, city names, etc.)

Is it possible to have those not display?

I noticed the Satellite map has the option. Why not the ROADMAP/

```
function initialize() {
var Nice = new google.maps.LatLng(43.7, 7.25);

var myOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: Nice,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use styled map types to turn off labels:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#StyledMapType

Here's a good builder for building the properties you want:

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html